# Exporting a variable so it appears in a script sourced through sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

I have a bash script/s which has a "main" script which is run as `sudo`.
Variables are declared in this script.
Then it sources another `commands.sh` script, however this script uses `sudo` to drop back to an ordinary user when sourcing the  `commands.sh` script.

file: `main.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

user=ubuntu
export $user

sudo -u $user bash -c "source includes-shared/commands.sh"
```

file: `includes-shared/commands.sh`

```
# debug command to see if $user is available
printenv
[ more commands...]
```

The variable `$user` no longer appears in this `commands.sh` script, i.e. it is not visible to `printenv` or other commands.
How can I export `$user` so that it is available to the sourced script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run export against the name of the variable. Right now, the variable is being referenced and replaced before export sees it.

Change it to this:

```
export user
```

Note the lack of `$`

Your current version is essentially this:

```
export ubuntu
```

Because `$user` is interpreted first.

You also lost your environmental variables when using sudo. There are two ways to preserve them. Either keep your entire environment

```
sudo -E -u $user command
```

Or just keep the variable you need

```
sudo user=$user -u $user command
```

Comment: thanks, that definitely makes sense, but I still get the same result when I don't use the `$`

Comment: @the_velour_fog  Sorry I'm used to using su instead of sudo so I missed a step!

Comment: no problem, `sudo -E -u $user command`  worked perfectly, thanks!